# Ctkinter. How do you set the curser in the entry widget and and output when "Enter" is pressed?

Tags: python, customtkinter

Please help me, I am trying to set the curser in the entry widget and when I press "enter" the word "yay" appears in the "name" entry widget in a frame class. I have tried everything but can't seem to succeed.
The end result will be when an account number is entered the details are fetched from a data file and displayed apon hitting "Enter".
My code below:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import keyboard

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")


class Frame1(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        # self.word = ""

        self.name = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Name", fg_color="transparent")
        self.name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

        self.name_x = ctk.CTkEntry(self, width = 300, placeholder_text="")     
        self.name_x.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")


   
class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("CRD Master")
        self.geometry("1000x650")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.acc_no = ctk.CTkEntry(self, width = 60, placeholder_text="Acc. no.")
        self.acc_no.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

        # self.button = ctk.CTkButton(self, width = 60, text="get", command=self.button_callback)
        # self.button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

        self.frame = Frame1(self)
        self.frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0), sticky="nsw")
        self.frame.name_x.focus_set()
        self.frame.name_x.bind("<Return>", command=self.keypress) 
        
    def keypress(self, event):
        word = "yay" 
        key = event.keycode
        if key == "Return":
            self.frame.name_x.insert(0, word)
 
app=App()
app.mainloop()
```

I tried moving the keypress function, bind and focus statements into the frame class. These statements are being ignored no matter where they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the [`keycode`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/key-names.html) is a number and not a string. So, when the `Enter` key is pressed it enters the `keypress` and reaches to `if key == "Return":` but never execute what inside the `if` block.

The function `keypress` is only called when you press the `Enter` key so there is no need to check that.

The following should work:

```py
    def keypress(self, event):
        word = "yay"
        self.frame.name_x.insert('0', word)
```

In addition, if you want the `word` to replace what the user wrote in the entry you should use the `delete` method:

```py
    def keypress(self, event):
        word = "yay"
        self.frame.name_x.delete("0", "end")
        self.frame.name_x.insert("0", word)
```